# Windows 7 Error Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 MSIGetProductInfo fails for {90120000-00A4-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}

Tags: windows-7, installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and during the installation, I got the following cryptic error:

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

MSIGetProductInfo failed to retrieve the ProductVersion
for package with Product Code = {90120000-00A4-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} 
Error code: 1605..

Sure enough, when I search the restistry, there is no CLSID or any other key for {90120000-00A4-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be the same issue as described here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/837dea3f-24b5-4362-8ee0-5e85efb2487c

> A. Uninstall failed SQL Server:
>
> Usually we can uninstall SQL Server
>   from Add and Remore Programs/Programs
>   and Features, and then we can
>   uninstall it. But sometimes, we cannot
>   uninstall all things of SQL Server, so
>   please run the Windows Installer
>   CleanUp Utility here to remove
>   installation information.
>
> B. Install System requirement programs:
>
> Install system requirement programs,
>   Windows Installer 4.5 or later
>   versiosn, .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET
>   Framework 3.5 SP1, these installation
>   medias can be downloaded form
>   Microsoft Download Center
>
> C. Install OWC11:
>
> Install OWC11, down from Microsoft
>   Download Center here: 
>   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7287252c-402e-4f72-97a5-e0fd290d4b76&DisplayLang=en

The OP in the thread linked above stated he installed OWC11 only long enough to remove them.  It's not entirely clear from the quoted text above that you can uninstall the OWC11 after installing them.  It seems that the poster in that thread had the additional problem that the OWC were not showing up under installed software which is why he was instructed to install the components again.

Comment: That was it, Installed OWC11; Removed OWC11; Installed SS with no problems;

Comment: Can you removed the Followed by: section from your answer, it just confuses things, then I'll remove this comment

Answer (score 0):

`1605` means `This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.`

As for the key, those ending `0FF1CE` are specific to Microsoft Office.

So, it seems to need Microsoft Office (or components of it) in order to continue with the installation...

Or perhaps you have it installed but it needs a repair?

---

I also saw someone mention:

> I was able to get the other services installed by going into my Add/Remove programs, removing any MS Office Web Components, restarting my machine, and then try to install the additional services.

So, removing Microsoft Office (or components of it) might also help...

Comment: I have office 2010 fully installed, that's what is odd about it; and a repair had no effect on the sqlserver 2008 r2 install process

Comment: What if you try to remove those Web Components or do a repair on Office? Perhaps you could remove Office, install SQL and then install Office again. It's weird, but there seems to be a conflict due to corruption in the Office Installer registry...

Comment: Well, there are no MS Office Web Components installed.  I have tried repair with no success. I'd hate to have to fully uninstall Office and reinstall it.  Maybe as a last resort :{